# How do I assign an EventTrigger to a reusable Button in its parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, eventtrigger

My reusable *Button* is basically a single button, of which *ControlTemplate* consists of a *TextBlock* and an *Image*. The *Text* property of *TextBlock* binds to a *DependencyProperty* to be exposed; similarly, the *Source* property of *Image* binds to a *DependencyProperty*. Here is the code for this *Button*.

```
<Button x:Class="Core.Resource.UserControlResource.NavigationButton1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core.Resource.UserControlResource"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="myself">
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="63"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="63"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Name="IconImage" Height="42" Width="42" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="{Binding ElementName=myself, Path=ScreenIcon}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=myself, Path=ScreenTitle}" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

where *ScreenTitle* and *ScreenIcon* are the aforementioned *DependecyProperty*.

Now, I want to use this *Button* in its "parent", a *UserControl*. The code will be like

```
<UserControl x:Class="Core.ParentControl"
         x:Name="parent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:usrCtrlResrc="clr-namespace:Core.Resource.UserControlResource;assembly=Core.Resource"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <usrCtrlResrc:NavigationButton1 ScreenTitle="sample Screen Title" ScreenIcon="/Core.Resource;component/MediaResource/pencilEdit.png">
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Name="txtBlk" Text="SampleSample"/>
</Grid>
```

However, in order to add reactions when the *Button* is clicked (say to change the *Grid.ColumnSpan* property of *TextBlock* "txtBlk" to 2), what I want to do else is assign *EventTriggers* to my reusable *Button* in the "parent". I initially thought of two ways, but none of them works.

- In my reusable *Button*, bind *Style.Triggers* to a *DependencyProperty* to get exposed to its "parent". However, it pops up "The property *Triggers* does not have an accessible setter".
- Move the *Style* of my reusable *Button* to a *ResourceDictionary* and assign a *Key* for the "parent" to use. However, by doing this, I am not sure how to handle my two *DependencyProperty*, because it is not supposed to have code-behind for a *ResourceDictionary* file.

Any other workarounds? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve this problem by directly override its Triggers. Code is as below.

```
<usrCtrlResrc:NavigationButton1 ScreenTitle=... ScreenIcon=...>
    <usrCtrlResrc:NavigationButton1.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="usrCtrlResrc:NavigationButton1.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        ...
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </usrCtrlResrc:NavigationButton1.Triggers>
</usrCtrlResrc:NavigationButton1>
```